# Shell Script to pass arguments to another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, shell-script

I am new to the linux and shell scripting. I have a script, which has some read commands in it. So,  something like

```
#script1.sh
echo "something here" 
....
read var1
read var2
...
```

Now, i want to write another script that calls this script and can pass the values to this script. So, i'm hoping for something like,

```
./script2.sh hello world
```

And, that would run script2 and store "*hello*" in var1 and "*world*" in var2. What should this **script2** contain and how can i pass these arguments to **script1**?

I  have searched for this a lot but i didn't find anyone explaining this.

Comment: Please start with a basic `bash` tutorial, for example [Bash scripting Tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial)

Comment: For the short answer see [Sharing variables across multiple shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/132698)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling script2.sh from script1.sh

```
#script1.sh
./script2.sh hello world
```

In script2.sh

```
var1 =$1 
var2 =$2
echo $var1
echo $var2
```

Ouput will be `hello world`